# integrating IDM to chrome or firefox

Tags: firefox, wine, google-chrome, idm

I have installed IDM through wine. But cannot integrate it to chrome or firefox. I want the feature like popping up the download menu on websites like youtube and other video websites. To be specific I would like to use IDM as same as in Windows, Can anyone help me? Or please suggest any alternatives that has the features like IDM.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Windows users are usually stuck with the flexibility of IDM when we switch to linux.
When I moved to Linux I have to find alternatives.

- youtube-dl (Its available in the command line- `$ man youtube-dl` to see usage)
- VideoDownloadHelper. --[Firefox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/)
- [4kdownloader](https://www.videohelp.com/software/4K-Video-Downloader/old-versions). I use this everyday. Download playlist and individual files, extract only the audio as well. Its paid app but the trick is, look for an older version and install. It works so well.
  I am using version 4.2.0